# How to abort running async/await xmlHttpRequest within componentWillUnmount?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, async-await, ecmascript-2017

This is the code... how would you abort such ajax call?

Or, how to prevent react from giving me an error "setState called on unmounted component"?

(httpGet is just a wrapper for XMLHttpRequest and a promise)

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await httpGet("/ajaxRequest");
    if(response) {
        //the component has already been unmounted
        this.setState(() => ({success: true}));
    }
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    //should abort possible running ajax
}
```

**EDIT:**
Here's the wrapper:

```
const httpGet = function (url) {


    const request = new XMLHttpRequest;
    request.open("GET", url, true);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>  {
        request.onload(response => {
            resolve(response);
        });

        request.onerror(() => {
            reject("Network error");
        });

        request.send();
    });
};
```

Comment: Can we khow how this wrapper looks ?

Comment: If you have control over the wrapper there is a pattern described in the React docs https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI I added the wrapper

Comment: Great @IvanHanák . I give you an answer. Enjoy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to abort it whenever you want, XMLHttpRequest wrapper should :

- Either return the request object itself  with the promise  .
- or make request creation outside the wrapper .
- Or use sub/pub library (like mufa or redux).

I will go with the second option

```
const httpGet = function (url, request = new XMLHttpRequest()) { // 2 arguments 

    request.open("GET", url, true);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>  {
        request.onload(response => {
            resolve(response);
        });

        request.onerror(() => {
            reject("Network error");
        });

        request.send();
    });
};
```

Now in `componentDidMount` :

```
async componentDidMount() {
    this.request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const response = await httpGet("/ajaxRequest", this.request);
    if(response) {
        //the component has already been unmounted
        this.setState(() => ({success: true}));
    }
}
```

Now in `componentWillUnmount`:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  if (this.request && this.request.abort) {
    this.request.abort();
  }
}
```

As simple as that.
And if you don't want to abort, so your first wrapper (httpGet) is still valid since the second argument (request)  is optional .

Comment: exactly - i've thought about something similar